# Qt remembering the last open folder

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I am using `QFileDialog::openfilename` for taking a file from user as input and I have specified the default folder which is to be shown when user open dialog.

But `qt` is somehow remembering the last open folder when filedialog is opened multiple times. But I want the default folder to be the the initial folder shown to the user not the last opened folder. In this, I am doing nothing explicitly to store the last opened information anywhere.

Please tell me what is the problem here and how to fix this.

Comment: Show you code of invoking `openFileName` and specifying a folder to open.

Comment: QString filePath= QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open Source Folder", path, "(*)");

Comment: Isn't this dialog wrapping the native dialog? Because that has the same behavior, at least on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It is clearly documented [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName).  The third parameter to getOpenFileName is *dir*.

> The file dialog's working directory will be set to *dir*. If *dir* includes a file name, the file will be selected.

Comment: It's documented clearly but if I am not saving the last opened folder information anywhere then every time when I will open the dialog it should open the same folder which I have given in the parameter not the last open folder.

Comment: I don't understand this comment.  Do you have access to the directory you want to open in or not?  If so, pass that as the third parameter.  If not, refer to QSettings.

Answer (score 1):

Use this. `setDirectory(str);` install default path and you never get the last opened directory.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFileDialog dia;
    dia.setDirectory("D:/");//or another default folder

    QString path1 = dia.getOpenFileName(this,"Choose file");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Qsettings with rewritting them down, you'll need a initialize with param path

```
void camera_index::writesetting_window() {
    //camera_index page
    QSettings settings("Moose Soft", "Clipper");
    settings.setValue("set_FOCUS", ui->camera_focus->value());
}

void camera_index::readsetting_window() {
    QSettings settings("Moose Soft", "Clipper");
    int FOCUS = settings.value("set_FOCUS").toInt();}
```

basically just set a fix value would help

Comment: I am struggling to see how this answer relates to the question, except that it uses QT Settings. Was this posted by mistake to the wrong question?